# Push git "Everything up-to-date " Dados não são realmente enviados

Tags: r, git

Estou fazendo PUSH para um repositório no gitlab.com . Recebo o retorno:

> warning: redirecting to
>   https://gitlab.com/fellipesillvaoff/Dados_Agronomia.git/ Everything
>   up-to-date

No meu entendimento Deu certo.
Na pratica as alterações não são enviadas.
Vi outras perguntas parecidas, e tentei segui os passos pelo git mas não conheço termos técnicos espero encontrar algo para leigo.

Comment: Você deu commit nas suas alterações? Se o seu HEAD local estiver igual o remoto, parece que vai aparecer esse erro/aviso mesmo.

Comment: como digito isso no git? eu mudei de commit no r várias vezes sem sucesso.

Comment: Se você fez alguma alteração, da um `git status` para saber quais foram, e vai dando `git add <FILE_NAME>` nos arquivos que foram alterados ou adcionados. Depois da um `git commit -m "Descrição das alterações"` para mandar para seu HEAD local e depois é só dar um `git push origin master` para enviar as alterações pro seu repositório remoto.

Comment: considerando que vc criou um novo branch, é necessário executar `git push -u origin <NOMEDABRANCH>`, assim todos que estão no projeto tb terão acesso a sua branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique se esta fazendo todas as etapas necessárias

Vejo que já esta com o repositório devidamente configurado, então, caso tenha criado novos arquivos, execute um `git add`

```
git add .
```

para adicionar todos os arquivos do diretorio

ou

```
git add <nome do arquivo>
```

para adicionar um arquivo especifico.
Depois dê um `commit`

```
git commit -m 'algum comentario sobre o commit'
```

E somente depois disso você executa o `push`

```
git push origin master
```

ou o branch especifico para o qual deseja enviar

```
git push origin <nome-do-branch>
```

Em todo caso, 
sempre vale a pena dar uma lida no [manual simplificado do git](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html) :)